How to match a number in a column to make sure its in another column
[excel][1]
What formula do i use to make sure the number in column B exists in any row within column A ?!


|----------------------------------------------------------------|---------------|-----------------------------------------------|
|Column_A                                                        |Column_B       |Decision(True/False)                           |
|202406260003915000015133679000000000000020002514C20200115       |336790         |True/ False                                    |
|----------------------------------------------------------------|---------------|-----------------------------------------------|




=SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH(B1, A:A))) > 0, If the text from Column found then It will return 1, otherwise 0.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

sorry i cant post an image, im using excel and i have a list of numbers in column A, and in column B, and i need to check to see if the number in column B is anywhere in the list of numbers in column A. and tell me if it is true or false.

You don't need to post an image. You can recreate the table using the markdown formatting available on stackoverflow. https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#tables

First you can check whether column B number found in column A or not and where a(SEARCH(B1, A:A), if found it will return some number. And then logically you can ask it is number and their sum product is more than 0.


|----------------------------------------------------------------|---------------|-----------------------------------------------|
|Column_A                                                        |Column_B       |Decision(True/False)                           |
|202406260003915000015133679000000000000020002514C20200115       |336790         |=SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH(B1, A:A))) > 0   |
|----------------------------------------------------------------|---------------|-----------------------------------------------|




thanks, that does work but when i auto fill the function downwards it breaks
=SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH(D5, A2:A10000))) > 0
=SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH(D6, A3:A10001))) > 0
=SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH(D7, A4:A10002))) > 0
i need it to stay at A2:A10000

You can use wildcards in a COUNTIF() function. This will count all the cells in column A that contain the value of B1 anywhere within it and ignoring letter case:
=COUNTIF(A:A,"*"&B1&"*")

That's not exactly what you want, though. You just want a true/false value. This works for that:
=COUNTIF(A:A,"*"&B1&"*")>0 

That breaks when the value in B1 is blank because "*"&B1&"*" becomes just ** which will match everything. You can escape that if you want:
=AND(B2<>"",COUNTIF(A:A,"*"&B1&"*")>0)

